# Как выводить несколько картинок для поста из WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Привет, использую вывод поста как вывод товара. Есть метабоксы под постом ( детальное описание, цена и.т.д). И вывожу через php все эти данные для каждого поста. Почти все идеально. Только есть слайдер с фотографиями, и я не знаю, как из админ панели выводить по несколько фотографий. К примеру, было бы очень хорошо, если мог бы выводить циклом. Покажу пример

```
<div>
<img src='imgProduct1.jpg>
<img src='imgProduct2.jpg>
<img src='imgProduct3.jpg>
<img src='imgProduct4.jpg>
<img src='imgProduct5.jpg>
<img src='imgProduct6.jpg>
<div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы я мог из админ панели добавлять несколько фотографий и выводить их разом через цикл или, может быть, как-то по-другому?

Comment: Тут ответ: [Как добавить картинки к посту без плагина](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/740982/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81/741052#741052)  Еще вы можете вместо контента вставлять меиафайлы потом распарсить

Answer (score 1):

Я вообще не понимаю вопрос, если это слайдер, то лучше всего сделать опять же через пост тайп. Каждый пост - слайд, у каждого слайда заголовок, описание, кастом урл, картинка ну и все что фантазии угодно.